# Where does gnome-keyring set $SSH_AUTH_SOCK?

Tags: gnome, openssh, ssh-agent, gnome-keyring

I am in the process of getting rid of `gnome-keyring` as an SSH agent.

## Things that I have done

- Searched the internet for hours.
- Changed stuff and restarted, often.
- Finally just `rm`-ed all the autostart stuff related to SSH.

That last thing magically worked as there is **no more** the socket for the agent there:

```
/run/user/[uid]/keyring/ssh
```

## Problem

The remaining problem is that **in spite** of my obtaining the wonderful aforementioned result, **something** in `gnome-keyring` still insists on setting `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` to the **now** *non-existing* socket above. It's like zombies, these things never die.

## Question

What is setting that variable and where is it done?

## Pitfalls

- I am **not** asking how I can reset that variable to another value.
- I am **not** asking how I can set that value system-wide or in a shell configuration file.
- I am **not** asking for some init-script voodoo incantations to freeze, set, reset, unset or replace anything.
- I am **not** asking for advice on how to uninstall the thing: I still need it for my passwords and it seems to be the most integrated and polished password manager in Gnome.

I want that thing disabled as it should be.

Comment: Uninstall gnome-keyring?

Comment: @rudimeier: I still need gnome-keyring for my passwords and as far as I know there is nothing more polished and integrated in Gnome.

Comment: @rudimeier even that doesn't seem to help. I've tried it.

Answer (score 12):

Let me guess - you're using Wayland. I ran into this problem today and figured I'd share the solution.

Gnome-Session has a hardcoded override for `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` under wayland for some reason. See the following commit: https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-session/commit/a8896ccad65583885735a04205351f48a42f29ae

The workaround? Set an environment variable to disable this behavior: `GSM_SKIP_SSH_AGENT_WORKAROUND=1`. This short-circuits the environment setting code.

For people that find this that are also trying to configure ssh-agent: In my systemd unit file for ssh-agent, I have the following line:

```
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/systemctl --user set-environment SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK GSM_SKIP_SSH_AGENT_WORKAROUND=1"
```

The full file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=SSH Agent
IgnoreOnIsolate=true

[Service]
Type=forking
Environment=SSH_AUTH_SOCK=%t/ssh-agent.socket
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh-agent -a $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/systemctl --user set-environment SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK GSM_SKIP_SSH_AGENT_WORKAROUND=1"

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Comment: Thanks! On Ubuntu v17.10 Artful Aardvark, simply adding `export GSM_SKIP_SSH_AGENT_WORKAROUND=1` to my ~/.profile and rebooting fixed my configuration that previously worked on v17.04.

Comment: This seems to affect more than just Wayland, I've been running into this when trying to use gnome-flashback + i3.

Comment: Please note that that hack works until Gnome 3.24 or older (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME/Keyring#Disable_keyring_daemon_components)

Comment: I see `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/[uid]/keyring/ssh` set with GNOME 3.34 (openSUSE Leap).

Comment: ... and that's *although* I set `GSM_SKIP_SSH_AGENT_WORKAROUND=1` in `~/.config/environment.d`.

Comment: There's more fun involved actually. By adding some debugging, I can see that the variable is set correctly in the first place (I want it to be `/run/user/$UID/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh`), but changed later on. It's correctly set when `.profile` is processed, but no more in `.bashrc`.

Comment: My problem was that the [recipe](https://newbedev.com/how-to-disable-the-keyring-for-ssh-and-gpg) I'd followed to disable the service wasn't effective. So the service started and **updated** the environment in the `systemd-user` instance, **overriding** previously-set values. To really disable the service, I had to set the [Hidden attribute](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html)  on it.

Comment: ... in case anyone wonders, the best place for *setting* `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is either `/etc/environment.d/50-ssh.conf` or `/etc/security/pam_env.conf`. Both allow referring to `${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}`.

Answer (score 6):

*(OP's environment is not known, so the paths given here are those found on my Ubuntu machine)*

### Where does gnome-keyring set SSH_AUTH_SOCK?

To answer the main question in title, SSH_AUTH_SOCK is set by gnome-keyring in `/usr/share/upstart/sessions/gnome-keyring-ssh.conf` with the following command:

```
initctl set-env --global SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

Quoting the `initctl` manual:

> `initctl set-env VARIABLE[=VALUE]`
>
> Adds  or  updates  a  variable in a job environment table. Variables set in this way will apply to all the subsequently-starting processes for a job.
>
> `-g`, `--global`
>
> Operate on the global job environment table and all existing running job environment tables.

### Where does SSH_AUTH_SOCK come from in the first place?

The `initctl` command above is conditioned to the fact that the environment variable SSH_AUTH_SOCK already exists. So, is it a chicken and egg situation? What sets it?

SSH_AUTH_SOCK is initially set by the original ssh-agent which is started at the very beginning of the X session. Quoting the manual:

> A UNIX-domain socket is created and the name of this socket is stored in the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable. The socket is made accessible only to the current user.

BUT, what the gnome-keyring's ssh component does is to substitute itself to the existing ssh-agent. Therefore it overwrites SSH_AUTH_SOCK with its own socket `/run/user/.../keyring-.../ssh` so that applications talk to it, and not to ssh-agent.

### How to disable it

Now, let's answer the last sentence "I want that thing disabled". What the OP wants is to disable the overwriting of SSH_AUTH_SOCK by the ssh component in gnome-keyring. They want to get back the "true" SSH_AUTH_SOCK variable initially set by ssh-agent.

The ssh component is started by the same startup script mentioned above (`/usr/share/upstart/sessions/gnome-keyring-ssh.conf`) but at one condition: the string `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false` must not be found in either of these files:

- (system-wide conf) `/etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop`
- (user conf) `~/.config/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop`

Therefore, if you want to disable it, all you have to do is add a line `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false` to one of these files, preferably the one in your HOME directory.

Comment: I've tried disabling the autostart entries for Gnome keyring and it seems the variable is still there, but points to a non-existing socket (so disabling the keyring worked, but the variable is set somewhere else). I am running an Archlinux machine so there is no upstart and there's nothing obvious in systemd that would set the variable..

Comment: @AndréBorie I know neither Arch nor systemd. What is the new value of the socket path? On my macihne, ssh-agent typically sets it to `/tmp/ssh-XXX/agent.PID`. Is ssh-agent still in your process list?

Comment: The path is just like in the original question. There are no SSH agents nor keyrings running.

Comment: This answer is really old but I hope you can help me too https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/422574/ssh-auth-sock-is-set-but-it-is-overwritten

Answer (score 3):

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME/Keyring#Disable_keyring_daemon_components

> If you wish to run an alternative SSH agent (e.g. ssh-agent or gpg-agent, you need to disable the ssh component of GNOME Keyring. To do so in an account-local way:
>
> ```
> mkdir ~/.config/autostart
> cp /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop ~/.config/autostart/ &&
> echo 'Hidden=true' >> ~/.config/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop
> ```
>
> Then log out.

Lightly editted, removing apparently useless use of `printf`

Comment: This also works for me on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: This is true for 3.24 and newer.

Answer (score 0):

As of Gnome 3.18, the socket appears to be stored in `~/.cache/keyring-(some random string)/ssh`

At a guess, it's being set by gnome-keyring-daemon.